# What can i do to speed up live reloading process after making changes in react app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have basic react app, created by create react app 2.
In start of project on my mac `2.2 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4` reload app after changes was very fast(like 1 sec), right now I have about 10 different screens of app and a ton of different files in project this process takes about 5 second and development process is a pain.

For styling i'm using `styled-components` and `antD`.
Import only necessary function from 3party packages regarding this issue:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4791
for example lodash:
`import isArray from 'lodash/isArray';`

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "reload app"? Is your app loading slow in the browser or is building your app slow?

Comment: @trixn live reload, building is slow